# Navigate to a specified position on a dynamic Angular 2 page

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing, ngfor, anchor-scroll

If I have scrolled down on a page where multiple elements have been generated on *ngFor, clicking on an element brings me to a different page via the router.
When I click on a button to get back to the previous page, I would like the screen to be scrolled down to the position I was in before I left the page.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look on [**#fragment**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html). It may help you.

Comment: Thanks, I did try fragment, but it tries to access the DOM before all the elements have been generated.

Comment: You may ask a new question with this issue. Someone could help you..

Comment: @j-meiring I am trying to achieve the same thing. Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @bob in the end we opened the new element using a modal to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose `List` page has `ngFor` loop like:

```
<div *ngFor="let note of (noteService.notes | async); let i = index" class="item" tabindex="0">
  <a (click)="edit(note, i, $event)">
    {{note.text}}
  </a>
</div>
```

In `edit` function, it provides additional index into url like `...?i=11`:

```
this.router.navigate(['group', this.noteService.groupName, 'edit', note.$key],
  { queryParams: { i: index } }); // pass in additional index in ngFor loop
```

`Edit` page remembers index as `this.noteIndex` in `ngOnInit`, then when going back:

```
this.router.navigate(['group', this.noteService.groupName],
  { queryParams: { i: this.noteIndex } }); // to let List page focus this note
```

Then `List` page's `ngOnInit` can do below:

```
this.noteService.announcedCountNotes.subscribe(
  count => {
    // noteService announces new count after it saves edit
    // so by now, ngFor should be ready
    if (idxToFocus) { // this.route.snapshot.queryParams['i'];
      setTimeout(_ => {
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('div.item');
        var len = elements.length;

        if (len > 0 && idxToFocus >= 0 && idxToFocus < len) {
          const el = elements[idxToFocus] as HTMLElement;
          //el.scrollIntoView();
          el.focus();
        }
      }, 0);
    }
  }
)
```

You might want to provide specific style for `div.item:focus`, this way worked at least on Chrome 59 (Windows 7 and iPad) for me.

Comment: I like the cleverness of getting the HTMLElements by using querySelectorAll